# Проблема с кодировкой, в браузере вместо символов вопросительные знаки

Tags: java, html, веб-программирование, netbeans

Я через Netbeans пишу проект на JAVA, и когда запускаю проект в браузере, вместо русских символов вопросительные знаки. Как можно исправить ошибку или настроить Netbeans правильно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
menutemplate.jsp

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">School</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Образование</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Студенты</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Преподователи</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Сотрудничество</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/action_page.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Поиск</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style><%@include file="/css/style.css"%></style>
        <title>Home Page</title>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="bg">
        <div class ="pokaz">
            <form action="allStudents" method="post">
                 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Показать всех студентов">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

homedecorator.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style><%@include file="/css/style.css"%></style>
        <title>Home Page</title>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="bg">
        <div class ="pokaz">
            <form action="allStudents" method="post">
                 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Показать всех студентов">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, у вас в настройках Netbeans указана кодировка не UTF-8, а ISO-8859-1.
Зайдите в свойства проекта в Netbeans и в категории исходные фалы установите UTF-8 в выпадающем списке кодирование. В файлах jsp можете убрать charset=ISO-8859-1 или установить charset=UTF-8. И скорее всего придётся перекодировать все jsp файлы, где есть кириллицы, из ISO-8859-1 в UTF-8, можно руками, а можно, скажем, notepad++ использовать.

Comment: Я в свойствах поставил UTF-8 но все так же

Comment: Правил вопрос посмотрите